# bind HTTServer to local ip:port so that others in LAN can see it?

Tags: python, networking

I want to run simple HTTP server on LAN to test it, how can I bind my local ip to this server so that everyone in the same LAN can see it?

```
 addr = ("192.168.10.14", 8765)
 srvr = HTTPServer(addr,RequestHandler)
```

I get this error :

**error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
addr = ("0.0.0.0", 8765)
```

Here is what i did:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

addr = ("0.0.0.0", 8765)

serv = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(addr, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

serv.serve_forever()
```

And got from an other machine:

```
192.168.1.2 - - [09/Nov/2010 22:26:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: @Gollu: hmm ? one second i will check

Comment: @Gollum : can you recheck again because i just test in my local network and it's working

Answer (score 15):

even simpler:

cd to dir you want to serve and run in terminal

```
python -m http.server 8888 --bind 0.0.0.0
```

then on another box on your lan enter

192.168.x.x:8888

in the browser where 192.168.x.x is the address of the serving box on your lan, which you will see in ifconfig output

Answer (score 4):

You can bind to all interfaces if you leave address as an empty string

```
addr = ("", 8765)
```

If you really want to bind to only one of your interfaces, first make sure you are entering address of the local interface, not address of some NAT device between you and your box.

Comment: I can only connect from my machine, if I do that. other machines on the same lan can not see this.

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: Empty string was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]`? [Python - SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html)

Comment: does not bind to local ip that others on same lan can see. so can't use. does not work, tried.

Comment: Too bad.  Be sure to download nmap http://www.nmap.org/.  It will help you diagnose firewall issues easily.  If you're running windows, you can use netstat -a to check what your computer is listening to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/netstat.htm